# Using Combine to trigger download on app activation not compiling

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to trigger a download when my app becomes active, but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is my code

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification).map{ _ in
    return self.urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
}
.tryMap{ element in
    guard let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
    httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
        throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
    }

.....
```

I have no idea how to get this to work. I constantly get a compile error stating:

`Value of type 'URLSession.DataTaskPublisher' has no member 'response'`

Why does my return statement return the complete publisher and not its result?

If I remove the `NotificationCenter` part and call `tryMap` directly on `dataTaskPublisher` like this:

```
        self.urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap{ element in
```

the compiler does not complain.

Pretty confused here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does my return statement return the complete publisher and not its result?

It returns the complete publisher because, well, you told it to return the complete publisher. A `map`'s `Output` is whatever the `map` transform returns. Your `map` transform returns a `DataTaskPublisher`, so the `Output` of the `map` is `DataTaskPublisher`. Therefore the `Input` to `tryMap`—the type of the `element` variable—is a `DataTaskPublisher`. Roughly speaking, the type after `map` (before `tryMap`) is

```
Publisher<Publisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), URLError>, Never>
```

(This is not a real type because `Publisher` is not a real type constructor.)

What you want is to flatten that out into

```
Publisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), Error>
```

You'll need to use `setFailureType(to:)` to convert the failure type of the notification publisher from `Never` to `Error`. And you'll need to use `mapError` to convert the failure type of the `DataTaskPublisher` from `URLError` to `Error`.

Once you've got the failure types matched up, there are several operators that can flatten nested publishers. The one you're looking for is probably [`switchToLatest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204759-switchtolatest):

```
func data(for url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .map({ _ in
            self.urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .mapError { $0 as Error }
        })
        .switchToLatest()
        .tryMap({ element in
            guard let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
            }
            return element.data
        })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```